# How to pass multiple DataServices to a component constructor in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I want to pass multiple DataServices to a component constructor. Currently I can pass them one by one, but I want to be able to pass them as a array in a more generic way.

```
export class MainGrid {

    constructor(private firstService: FirstDataService, private secondService: SecondDataService) { }
    // how to do this instead -> constructor(private services: BaseDataService[] ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.firstService.getData().then(data => {
        // do something with data
      });

      this.secondService.getData().then(data => {
        // do something with data
      });

      // how to do this instead ->
      this.services.map((service) => {
        service.getData().then(data => {
          // do something with data
        }
      });

    }
}
```

Here is what I have for BaseDataService

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import {Data} from '../../app/data/data';


export abstract class BaseDataService {

    constructor() {}

    abstract getData()
}

@Injectable()
export class FirstDataService implements BaseDataService{

    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    getData() {
        return this.http.get('app/resources/data/cars-medium.json')
                    .toPromise()
                    .then(res => <Data[]> res.json().data)
                    .then(data => { return data; });
    }
}

@Injectable()
export class SecondDataService implements BaseDataService {

    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    getData() {
        return this.http.get('app/resources/data/cars-medium.json')
                    .toPromise()
                    .then(res => <Data[]> res.json().data)
                    .then(data => { 
                        return {
                            foo: 'bar'
                        }
                    });
    }
}
```

So my question is how and where to pass this array of BaseDataService to the MainGrid component constructor?